# Element is not clickable at point (617, 690.5). Other element would receive the click: <th>...</th> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I get the error above when trying to press the "add" button on the integration test I am trying to implement.  I thought that was a delay with the javascript, and I tried the following, but none of them worked:

```
Then /^I should click "([^"]*)"$/ do |selector|
  # if page.should have_selector(selector)
  # find(selector).click
  # end
  # page.execute_script("$(#{selector}).click()")
  find(selector).click
end
```

I tried all of the above, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where's the code? What's the problem?

Comment: Prior to downvoting, I suggest we comment on the questions first, asking - especially new users, to add some code for example.

Answer (score 5):

This is hardly a great answer, but I'll give it anyway...

I've only ever seen this problem when testing with Chrome. There are two solutions that worked for me:

- Use Firefox instead of Chrome
- Instead of `find(selector).click`, use `page.execute_script("$(#{selector}).click()")`

But since you've tried the second option and it didn't work, try using Firefox instead. Sorry :(

Comment: Dude I had so many problems with `click()`.  Use firefox.  All the things solved.  Wish I could upvote you a few more times!

Answer (score 5):

I found resizing the browser window made a similar problem go away:

```
 Given(/^I open a new browser window$/) do
   Capybara.current_session.current_window.resize_to(1000, 1000)
 end
```

Comment: That works well if you have a "Toast" over the target element. Making the window larger moved the "Toast" away from the target element.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error in Capybara when trying to click_button a 'Save' button at the end of a page. Scrolling and bringing the element to view using JS proved to be an effective workaround.

```
def scroll_to(element)
  script = <<-JS
  arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);
  JS
  Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.execute_script(script, element.native)
  element # return the element
end

scroll_to(
  find(:xpath, '//button[text()=\'Save\']')
).click
```

**Update**

---

For me, it turned out to be a mismatch between the version of installed Chrome and Chromedriver and no code change was necessary after all.

Chrome 61+ includes modifications to scrolling behaviors. A quick examination of Chromedriver page revealed that I had to upgrade my Chromedriver (from 2.29 to 2.32) in order to make the driver compatible with those changes. This was part of the Chromedriver 2.30 (Supports Chrome v59-61) release notes:

- Fixes a bug where Chromedriver fails to click due to page scrolling changes in Chrome 61+.

Answer (score 0):

I had a sticky header that was preventing Selenium from sending the click to the right radio button on both Chrome and Firefox (though Poltergeist worked fine). This is a hack to delete all fixed elements (like sticky headers), and it worked for me:

```
def kill_sticky_headers
  # https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/kill-sticky-headers/
  script = <<-EOS
  (function () {
    var i, elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (getComputedStyle(elements[i]).position === 'fixed') {
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
      }
    }
  })();
  EOS
  page.execute_script script
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar problem where I have to check two check boxes one after the other. But I was getting the same above error, hence I added a wait in between my steps for checking the checkboxes. It's working fine and great.

Here are the steps:-

```
  When I visit /administrator/user_profiles
  And I press xpath link "//*[@id='1']"
  Then I should see "Please wait for a moment..."
  When I wait for 5 seconds
  And I press xpath link "//*[@id='2']"
  Then I should see "Please wait for a moment..."
  When I visit /administrator/user_profiles_updates
```